# Is "Selected 1 of 1 Entries" correct pluralization?

Tags: grammatical-number

I'm trying to work out any possible pluralization strings for an application that handles dynamic values, and I'm a little stuck on the English here.. What I think sounds right doesn't feel right.

Pluralization options:

- Selected 1 entry (correct)
- Selected 2+ entries (correct)

But if I want to include the total as well:

- Selected 1 of 1 entries (is this correct? it sounds correct to me)
- Selected 0 of 1 entries (is this correct?)
- Selected 1 of 2 entries (correct)

I know it's trivial, but these little details matter to me..

**EDIT:** If the count is the max, another option is to express this as:

- Selected all 2 entries (correct)
- Selected all 1 entry (this doesn't sound correct? is it?)

Comment: You can never say **one entries*.

Comment: @tchrist i added an edit.. would it be singular there as well?

Comment: I also think "1 of 1 entry" is correct. However, expressions such as "1 of 1 entries" are quite common, for example on Facebook ("There are 1 new items" on your timeline, etc.). Give that this distinction can easily be taken care of in any programming language, I'd go for correct grammar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using *entries* for a single entry is not correct, which can be demonstrated by describing them/it. Adding an adjective to break up a standard expression helps analysis because it’s no longer the customary expression which “just **is**”:

> There is 1 available entry *(Indisputably correct)*
> Selected 1 of 1 available entry *(Follows by analogy)*
>
> There are 2 available entries *(Indisputably correct)*
> Selected 1 of 2 available entries *(Follows by analogy)*
>
> There are 1 available entries *(Indisputably wrong)*
> There is 1 available entries *(Indisputably wrong)*
> Selected 1 of 1 available entries *(Wrong by analogy)*

Using “1 of 1 entries” probably sounds right because

- it’s very common
- the “1 of” implies that there is more than one available, and therefore *entries* might be expected to follow it.

but just because “everyone does it” doesn’t make it correct.